# Magento2 Setup version for module is not specified

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I installed a local copy of Magento 2. I am facing some problem with custom module.

I followed following file/folder structure

`app/code/Ps/HelloWorld/etc/module.xml`:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Ps_HelloWorld" schema_version="0.0.1" setup_version="0.0.1" />
</config>
```

Inside this file I have the following: I refreshed the store cache and then I got:

> Setup version for module 'Ps_HelloWorld' is not specified.

Comment: remove the `schema_version` and then try

Comment: its not working

Comment: Try clearing cache on the command line using `bin/magento cache:flush` from your public folder

Comment: Also, schema_version is being removed in the later versions of the beta from what i have heard

Comment: this error is also thrown if a module is referenced in config.php but is not installed

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
php -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Module_Name
php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

*Assuming that you are run the current master branch and not dev branch*

Comment: can you please explain in detail why we need to run `php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade` command

Comment: Ssh into your server then cd to magento root folder

Comment: R.S is there a magento2 official link specifying all these commands.

Comment: @huzefam http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands.html

Comment: you can get list of all commands by runnning `php -f bin/magento`, either it will also provide what is the purpose of each and every command

Answer (score 33):

In my case it was the file/folder permission of that module.

Apache couldn't read the configuration file.

Apply following permission to your module directory.

```
chmod 775 <module path> -R
```

Comment: Yes in my case this was the problem .. thanks ;)

Comment: After a huge search, i had saw this answer and tried as a final try. Oh my god, my issue get solved.  Thank you so much @Nahid Bro :)

Comment: This solved my issue as well

Answer (score 13):

Reference source: https://magentoexplorer.com/magento-2-setup-version-for-module-is-not-specified-how-to-fix
(in my case, i got this error when creating a new Magento 2 module)

You may encounter this error because of wrong module file/folder permission, you can change permission for module folder as follow

```
chmod 775 <module path> -R
```

There's another possibility that you forgot to add **registration.php** and **composer.json** in module. Try to add the following file

**/app/code/Namespace/Module/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Namespace_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

and **/app/code/Namespace/Module/composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "namespace/module",
    "description": "namespace",
    "require": {
      "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
      "magento/framework": "100.0.*",
      "magento/module-ui": "100.0.*",
      "magento/module-config": "100.0.*",
      "magento/module-contact": "100.0.*"    
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "100.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "Namespace/Module"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "namespace\\module\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Finally run these commands

```
php -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Module_Name
magento setup:upgrade
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

An additional scenario where this has come up for me was due to performing a pull on my project's repository and the module had been removed from the file system. While this was intentional, there remained at the time lingering configuration for it in Magento's configuration file.

Removing the reference to the module from `app/etc/config.php` resolved my issue.

**TL;DR**

I did first try disabling the module using the CLI's `module:disable VendorName_ModuleName` command and the response back from the CLI was `Unknown module(s): 'VendorName_ModuleName'`. I assume this is because it was already missing from the file system. Since there weren't intentions of using the module ever again, manual removal of it from `app/etc/config.php` at this point seems appropriate anyway.

Comment: The tl;dr is longer than the initial paragraph...

Comment: @StevieG I still smile every time I come back to this hahahaha... 

When I first wrote this I did not know what TL;DR meant I believe. That the "tl;dr" portion is additional info that is intended to be skipped if you so choose or something.

Answer (score 1):

Open your Database and find the table `setup_module`.

Your module `Ps_HelloWorld` should be in this table.

If not found try to enter manually.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and it was because PHP Opcache was enabled and based on my settings any updates to any PHP file did not get updated in the cache.

You can clear opcache by creating a file **clear_opcache.php** and enter the code below.

```
<?php
opcache_reset();
?>
```

Then you can run

```
php clear_opcache.php
```

Or in my case I can restart the php-fpm service for RHEL

**Centos/RHEL 7**

```
systemctl restart php-fpm
```

**Centos/RHEL 6 or older**

```
service php-fpm restart
```

You can find other ways to restart php-fpm here
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-reload-restart-php7-0-fpm-service-linux-unix/

Answer (score 0):

Problem : the file `app/etc/config.php` was copied from another magento instance (because of a bad file manipulation). Because of that, I had the same symptoms than described in this question.

The solution was to delete all modules names that wasn't in the instance of Magento where the problem occured, and it worked out fine.

Note that a better solution would have probably been to `bin/magento module:status` , and then `bin/magento module:disable` for all the module with problems.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. My setup was through docker, doing php container down, then up cleared cache and resolved the issue.